# Global Inline Functions

Tags: c++

I have here a singleton class, called `Master`. This class has some other entities that do a specific job. The `Master` class has a `get` method for these entities.

```
namespace Framework {
    class Master {
    private:
        NetworkController * mNetworkController;
        FileController * mFileController;

        static Master * gInstance;

    public:
        static Master * getInstance();

        NetworkController * getNetworkController();
        FileController * getFileController();
    }
}
```

I use these entities allthoughout the program like so:

```
Framework::Master::getInstance() -> getNetworkController()
Framework::Master::getInstance() -> getFileController()
```

As you can see, it's a bit long and time-consuming to type in. So I tried putting them in a macro, like so:

```
#define NETWORK_CONTROLLER() Framework::Master::getInstance() -> getNetworkController()
#define FILE_CONTROLLER() Framework::Master::getInstance() -> getFileController()

namespace Framework {
    class Master {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, I find this method messy and confusing. So I tried `inline` methods and added them in one header file.

```
#ifndef __FrameworkHelper__
#define __FrameworkHelper__

inline Framework::NetworkController * MasterNetworkController() { return Framework::Master::getInstance() -> getNetworkController(); }
inline Framework::FileController * MasterFileController() { return Framework::Master::getInstance() -> getFileController(); }

#endif
```

But it gave me compile errors when trying to use them on a different class saying:

```
error C2653: 'Framework' : is not a class or namespace name
```

I don't know why it would throw an error like this. How can I make these inline methods available allthroughout my program?

Comment: You'll need to post more of the header code for where you've defined the `inline`s to show where the issue is.

Comment: Singletons cause all kinds of trouble, don't they?

Comment: @doctorlove I agree, but I don't have the time to rewrite the whole Framework without using singletons. Bad design choice. :(

Comment: Have you `#include`d the `Framework` header?

Comment: Did you include the header containing the definition of Master before you include the helper header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reference of the `namespace framework` in your header file, you can fix it by doing :

```
#ifndef __FrameworkHelper__
#define __FrameworkHelper__

#include "Framework.h" // where the framework is defined

inline Framework::NetworkController * MasterNetworkController() { return Framework::Master::getInstance() -> getNetworkController(); }
inline Framework::FileController * MasterFileController() { return Framework::Master::getInstance() -> getFileController(); }

#endif
```

Or in your framework header :

```
#ifndef __Framework__
#define __Framework__

namespace Framework {
    class Master {
        ...
    }
}

inline Framework::NetworkController * MasterNetworkController() { return Framework::Master::getInstance() -> getNetworkController(); }
inline Framework::FileController * MasterFileController() { return Framework::Master::getInstance() -> getFileController(); }

#endif
```

But I prefer the first solution....

Another solution, instead of using your `inline` methods would be to set the `getNetworkController` and `getFileController` `static` and use them like :

```
Master::getNetworkController();
Master::getFileController();
```

In my own opinion it would be easier to understand.

Comment: I was having header file issues when using method 1. So I added the inline definition below the `Master` class definition and it seemed to run fine. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Quicker : set your `getNetworkController` and `getFileController` methods `static` as well as `getInstance`, and implement them like this :

```
NetworkController * getNetworkController() {
    return Master::getInstance()->mNetworkController;
}
```

You could even set your `mFileController` and `mNetworkController` static, as `Master` is a singleton.

To solve your problem as you ask it, you need to include the header containing `Framework` namespace definition in your FrameworkHelper header (be careful of cross-inclusion however).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, it's out of the question scope, but I'd recommend you to avoid using that "Framework::Master::getInstance()->..." staff at all.

Your client code should have no idea is it singleton instance or local temporary stub (for testing purposes, or history undo-redo snapshots, for example). So the only place you have to type that long-messy accessor staff is module init code (so you just put a reference into it and then forget about "Framework::Master::getInstance()->...". Just access it via locally-remembered reference.